# How to build single .exe file with multiple files in python using cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Using Python 3.5 and cx_freeze 5.0.1

```
**MY Folder Structure :**
Main_file.py, 
Log.py, 
ExcelOperations.Py, 
TestData.xlsx, 
Config.ini,  
PsExec.exe (For remote execution)
```

I am trying to create single .exe file for Main_file.py which is imported with [Log.py,ExcelOperations.Py and OS, subprocess,configparser are imported in Main_file.py file]

My Setup.py file

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}
base = None
setup( name = "guifoo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("Main_file.py", base=base)])
```

#
After creating build with above setup file my Main_file.exe file is not working as expected [It just launches and closes the cmd in a mili sec]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: have you tried starting the exe via command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and I am getting an import error.   File "C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\s
te-packages\xlwt-1.2.0-py3.5.egg\xlwt\ExcelFormula.py", line 3, in <module>
   from . import ExcelFormulaParser, ExcelFormulaLexer
importError: cannot import name 'ExcelFormulaParser'

Comment: I would include that in the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cx_freeze isn't collecting all of the required modules for the xlwt package. Try editing your `build_exe_options` variable to include the xlwt package

`build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "xlwt"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}`

Comment: Thanks.. After including packages in setup file it is working for me.